# Java RMI: Clients as Primary and Backup Server

Tags: java, rmi, distributed-computing

Am currently doing a school project where the aim is to practice using RMI to create a distributed system.

The idea is similar to BitTorrent where each client will connect to a centralized tracker (as a bootstrapping point) to be able to get the list of clients, then one client will step up to become the primary server whose methods will be invoked by the rest of the clients.

The catch is that **only** the Tracker can be registered onto the RMI Registry.

I was able to do it by registering the primary server into the registry as well but seems like it violates this rule.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much

Comment: Add a method to the tracker to get the client which is currently acting as the server. It isn't clear from your description who makes that decision, or how. Presumably the tracker should do it. Each client must implement a remote interface and either extend `UnicastRemoteObject` or call `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject()` on itself.

Comment: I managed to get it to work by passing the exported interface to the tracker and let other clients get this instance from the Tracker.

Thank you!